# Gremlin operation using python in Azure functions

Tags: python, azure, graph, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

Is was trying to create Azure function using Python(Http trigger) to fetch data from the gremlin graph.
I used 
from gremlin_python.driver import client as clientDriver
to import the libraries and it was working fine locally.

When i deploy the same code to the Azure portal and ran the code, am getting 500 internal error.
After trying some changes, i could see "from gremlin_python.driver import client as clientDriver" import statement is not working(When i remove this piece the code works)

When we run the code in VSCode, we are creating a virtual env and installing the gremlin packages, so it was working in local and not in Azure portal.

Could someone help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: Hi Gokul, may I know if the solution works ?

Answer (score 1):

For this problem, we need to make sure the `requirements.txt` is all right. And if you just do the import module by the line

```
from gremlin_python.driver import client as clientDriver
```

You need to add another line to import the `gremlin_python.driver` module explicitly.

```
import gremlin_python.driver
```

Hope it helps~

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I Tried it as mentioned in the article
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python

Will try out yours as well